# Angular 2 routing in ASP.Net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a Angular 2 application using ASP.Net Core application. The routing doesn't seem to work. When I execute the application the app.html page is shown as it is mentioned in the startup.cs file. I should be able to navigate via url when I type for example localhost/risks etc. Please also not that the routing loop in app.html doesnt show anything since the routes arent initialized. I see the app.html only with heading  MVC, Angular2 and sample.

Could somebody help me with this please?

[Application Folder Structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXFkv.png)

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from '../app.component';
import { RiskListComponent } from './risks/risk-list.component';
import { RiskDetailsComponent } from './risks/risk-detail.component';
import { RiskService } from './risks/risk.service';

import {
    LocationStrategy,
    HashLocationStrategy
} from '@angular/common';

import { routing,
    appRoutingProviders}  from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, RiskListComponent, RiskDetailsComponent],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders, RiskService, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RiskListComponent } from './risks/risk-list.component';
import { RiskDetailsComponent } from './risks/risk-detail.component';



const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: RiskListComponent },
    { path: 'risks/:id', component: RiskDetailsComponent },

];


export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

risk-list.component.html

```
<h3 class="first">{{title}}</h3>
<!--[rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="2" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]"-->
<!--<p-paginator rows="10" totalRecords="100" pageLinkSize="3"></p-paginator>-->

<div>{{risks | json}}</div>

<p-dataTable [value]="risks" [paginator]="true" rows="5" totalRecords="100" pageLinkSize="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]"  [sortMode]="multiple" sortField="inceptionDate" [sortOrder]="1" >
    <header>List of Risks</header>




        <!--<footer>Choose from the list.</footer>-->

        <p-column field="reference" header="Reference (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="insuredName" header="Insured Name (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="inceptionDate" header="Inception Date (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="riskType" header="Risk Type (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="status" header="Status (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="grossPremium" header="Gross Premium (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="allocatedTo" header="Allocated To (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="allocatedCompany" header="Allocated Company (contains)" [filter]="true" sortable="true"></p-column>

</p-dataTable>
```

risk.ts

```
export class Risk {
    riskId: number;
    reference: string;
    insuredName: string;
    inceptionDate: string;
    riskType: string;
    status: string;
    grossPremium: number;
    allocatedTo: string;
    allocatedCompany: string;

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTable, Column } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { Router } from  '@angular/router';
import {  Routes, RouterModule } from  '@angular/router';
import { RiskListComponent } from './components/risks/risk-list.component';
import { RiskDetailsComponent } from './components/risks/risk-detail.component';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import './rxjs-operators';


//import { RiskService } from './components/risks/risk.service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `
        <div>
            <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
              <rm-risks> </rm-risks> 
        </div>
         <nav>
          <a routerLink="/dashboard" >Dashboard</a>
          <a routerLink="/risks" >Risks</a>

        </nav>
        <div>
          <router-outlet>  </router-outlet>
        </div>
         `
        // <a routerLink="/riskdetails" routerLinkActive="active">RiskDetails</a>
        //< a routerLink="/welcome" routerLinkActive="active" > Welcome < /a>
        //,
        //directives: [RiskListComponent, DataTable, Column],

    })

    export class AppComponent {
        pageTitle: string = 'Test UK Trader';
    }
```

app.html

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1>
    MVC, Angular2
    <br>
    <small>Sample</small>
</h1>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sunglasses"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul *ngIf="routes != null" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li *ngFor="#rt of routes" [class.active]="getLinkStyle(rt)">
                <a [routerLink]="[rt.name]">{{rt.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="content padding has-header">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Glimpse;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions;

namespace AspNetCoreAngularDemo1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           // services.AddGlimpse();
            services.AddMvc();
        }


        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                // If there's no available file and the request doesn't contain an extension, we're probably trying to access a page.
                // Rewrite request to use app root
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/app/app.html"; // Put your Angular root page here 
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200; // Make sure we update the status code, otherwise it returns 404
                    await next();
                }
            });

            // Serve wwwroot as root
            app.UseFileServer();

            // Serve /node_modules as a separate root (for packages that use other npm modules client side)
            app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
            {
                // Set root of file server
              //  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(environment.ApplicationBasePath, "node_modules")),
                // Only react to requests that match this path
                RequestPath = "/node_modules",
                // Don't expose file system
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
            });


            //app.UseMvc(routes =>
            //{
            //    routes.MapRoute("default",
            //                    "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //    routes.MapRoute("spa-fallback",
            //                    "{*anything}",
            //                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            //    routes.MapWebApiRoute("defaultApi",
            //                          "api/{controller}/{id?}");
            //});




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to load exactly? `localhost/risks` or `localhost/risks/123`?

Comment: localhost/risks and localhost/

Comment: Please also not that the routing loop in app.html doesnt show anything since the routes arent initialized. I see the app.html only with heading  MVC, Angular2 and sample

Comment: Does `localhost/risks/123` load successfully?

Comment: Nothing loads. Because the routing isn't working as desired , I am  unable to test the service.

Comment: The only thing I can tell you right now is that `localhost/risks` will not load unless you have a corresponding `'risks'` route entry. The `'id'` route parameter is not optional with your current configuration.

Comment: What change do I need to make ? Could you be bit more clear ?

Comment: Another point is that the the blank route should load the risklistcomponent as per my route configuration. so if i type the url localhost/ , it should ideally load the risklistcomponent

Answer (score -1):

I see that you specified router-outlet in both app.html and app.component. I think it might be confusing.

Comment: I commented out the router-outlet in my app.component and specified a template url to point to app.html. This does not make any difference. I am not expecting data to load in app.html as there is no service hookup mentioned in app.components. The service hookup is in the risk-list.component.ts. So What I need to get working is , the risk-list.component.ts should load when the user types, localhost/risks. The outut of data is expected in risk-list.component.html.